# reference class library in ssis script task

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, ssis

i have a solution containing a class library project and a sql server integration services project ...
now i want to call the code of the class library from a script task in ssis package ...

in fact i need to add linq to sql classes to my script task in ssis package which seems to be unavailable ... instead i want to add the linq to sql classes to my class library and call it's functions from script task ...

the class library function :

```
public static void dosomelinqstuff(){
    // using linq to sql
}
```

and in script task i want to be able to call :

```
someclass.dosomelinqstuff();
```

any suggestions to solve my problem ?

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the use of "Web Service Task" ? If you can provide a web service interface to your method, you can call it by the provided WebService Task.